# Laravel inject data in input before store

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in the store function in my controller I have:

```
public function store()
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Item::$rules);

        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }

        Item::create($data);

        return Redirect::route('spesas.index');
    }
```

What is missing is the user_id field.

I tought since the inserting user is the auth one, to not pass the id via POST, but retrieve it with Auth::user() in the controller (It seemed more secure).

Now I have the problem to insert the Auth::user() id in the input fields before Item::create($data);

Am I doing the Right Thing? Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Laravel. But what speaks against `$data['user_id'] = Auth::id();` before creating the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the cleaner solution I found is to inject, in the constructor of the model, the correct id. So I'll free the controller of the hassle ( and avoid duplicated code)

Comment: Please write down your code snippet so that people can know what you had used actually.

Answer (score 2):

Just add your user id to the $data array by doing:

```
$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
```

Simple as that. :-)

Alternatively, you could have a hidden input field named 'user_id' and add the currently authorised users id as the fields value. Up to you.

Comment: I'll try the first solution. The hidden field opens a whole lot of other problems, since a malicious user can modify it and associate Items to other users.

Comment: True, though you could perform a check to see if the id passed corresponded to Auth::user()->id and if it didn't return back with the appropriate response.

Answer (score 1):

The good old `+` sign will help you here:

```
Item::create($data + ['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
```

Comment: Nope :/ Still gave me

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 Item.user_id may not be NULL (SQL: insert into "items" ("amount", "context_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (2, 2, 2014-08-18 07:11:41, 2014-08-18 07:11:41))

Comment: Uhm actually seems that Auth::id() is empty :_| (and I am sure I'm authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Auth::user()->id`, not `Auth::id()`

Or

```
$item = new Item($data);
Auth::user()->items()->save($item);
```

Comment: Why not to use `Auth::id()` ?